# multiple commands produce error in xcode 11.4 react native my copy bundle resources are empty

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

following is the error in xcode
I have also tried build legacy from workspace settings but failed to do so.

Multiple commands produce '/Users/saifubaid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/antispam-bjwrxskogxnnophfhgkpyxxcqcuj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/antispam/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle':

1. Target 'React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/saifubaid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/antispam-bjwrxskogxnnophfhgkpyxxcqcuj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/antispam/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
2. Target 'React-Core.common-CoreModulesHeaders-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/saifubaid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/antispam-bjwrxskogxnnophfhgkpyxxcqcuj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/antispam/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
   stuck on it. tried almost every solution.

Answer (score 6):

Multiple commands produce '/Users/shubhamnagota/dev/zest/zest-app/ios/DerivedData/zestapp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/zestapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle':

Click on Pods App
[image: Click on Pods App]

From the list remove React-Core-AccessibilityResources
[image]

Clean Project
Build Again
Archive.
Worked for me! :)

Comment: Thank you so much this is only thing that worked for me ,

Comment: Perfect answer save time and efforts.